# i want number to be converted into dates by applying vba code

Tags: excel, vba

currently i am working on a huge worksheet (it is basically data entry work.)

if i type 2572019 then vba should convert it to 25/7/2019.

please let me know if it is possible. i am completely noob in vba.

```
Sub fomat_date()

ActiveCell.Cells.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End Sub
```

Comment: is this the only way you will be using it `2572019` ? because the formula you used will convert is to an unrecognizable date.

Comment: Yes it is possible but then ensure that you enter the number in `dmmyyyy` format. For example `2072019` for `2/7/2019` or `20072019` for `20/07/2019`. You can handle that in Worksheet_Change Event

Comment: input is 2072019 and my code output it 28/12/7572
Siddharth

Comment: Your code will not give you the results you want unless you change the format of the cell before entering the Number. Because if you enter the number as `General` default cell formatting, your code will convert it to absurd dates. Like you got now :)

Comment: If you want to convert `2572019` to a date, you need to manipulate it using `Mid`, `Left`and `Right`

Comment: @salman when you input `2072019` then you will have to use  `Mid`, `Left` and `Right` in `Worksheet_Change Event` to get `2/7/2019`

Comment: So what date would 2122019 be?  21 Feb or 2 Dec?  You can't expect Excel to be able to guess.

Comment: @Gareth if you go by what i suggested `dmmyyyy format` then it will be 2 dec 2019...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

hello maybe use something like this :

if the month is 1 number your string will be of size seven else if your string is size 8 we can say that the month would be 2 number.

This would work only if the day is set as 01 and not 1 for exemple ..

```
If Len("2572019") = 7 Then 
    MsgBox Left("2572019", 2) & "/" & Mid("2572019", 3, 1) & "/" & Right("2572019", 4)
end if

If Len("2572019") = 8 Then 
    Left("2572019", 2) & "/" & Mid("2572019", 3, 2) & "/" & Right("2572019", 4)
end if
```

**Edit :**

```
If Len(Cells(1,1).Value) = 7 Then 
        Cells(1,1).Value = Left(Cells(1,1).Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(Cells(1,1).Value, 3, 1) & "/" & Right(Cells(1,1).Value, 4)
    end if

If Len(Cells(1,1).Value) = 8 Then 
  Cells(1,1).Value =  Left(Cells(1,1).Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(Cells(1,1).Value, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(Cells(1,1).Value, 4)
end if
```

Edit 2 :

```
sub tryme()

Dim rng As range
Dim cell as range

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Selection" , Type:=8)

For Each cell in rng

If Len(cell.Value) = 7 Then 
        cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(cell.Value, 3, 1) & "/" & Right(cell.Value, 4)
    end if

If Len(cell.Value) = 8 Then 
  cell.Value =  Left(cell.Value, 2) & "/" & Mid(cell.Value, 3, 2) & "/" & Right(cell.Value, 4)
end if

next cell

end sub
```

Comment: i am unble to use your code sir. some compile error is showing.

Comment: m i doing in a right way?       Sub Date_format()


 
 If Len("2572019") = 7 Then Left("2572019", 2) & "/" & Mid("2572019", 3, 1) & "/" & Right("2572019", 4)

    If Len("2572019") = 8 Then Left("2572019", 2) & "/" & Mid("2572019", 3, 2) & "/" & Right("2572019", 4)

End Sub

Comment: @SalmanB just copy my edit with the `end if` add ;) I wait for your **feedbacks**

Comment: @SalmanB can you copy and paste your new sub ? I will double check make sure to add **space** **before** and **after** **&**

Comment: it is working now. but the thing is i dont need it in msg box. i want it in excel to be pasted. e.g   in A1 2572019 is entered then code should change it in date as it is showing in msg box, instead of msgbox it should change it in same cell or selection of cells.

Comment: @SalmanB at the end of the Answer I added you what you need, please try it

Comment: yes this code is working perfctly fine but i need it in active cell. as i am gonna input dates in cells. so when i select all cells and run this code so all number should be converted in to date. basically i need it  activecell and selection of cell. overall it is perfect.

Comment: what would be the range selected @SalmanB ? a column ? or will you select it with the hand ?

Comment: @SalmanB please see Edit 2 and give me feedbacks (I didn't check yet )

Comment: For Each cell In rng.Adress  - object doesnt suport this property or method.  showing this error

Comment: i remove adress and now its working. thank you so much for your hardwork sir. thank you all of you.